# How to split a dataset with peaks and finding area under these peaks?

Tags: python, pandas, split, sum

I have two datasets, one with consumption of energy and one with production of energy. I merged these two and filtered out all of the surplus energy peaks from this. This resulted in a dataframe with lots of peaks and zeros for all moments there is no surplus energy.

What I am looking for is to find the amount of energy in each peak. More or less this means finding the area under each indivivual peak, from the moment it starts from zero to returning to zero.

I -unsucesfully- tried to split the peaks everytime the graph hits zero. I simply have no idea on how to code something that will split the dataset into individual peaks or -for that matter- calculate how much energy there is in every peak. It is too much data to do this by hand (almost a year of data in 15-minute intervals).

Simply summing all the data and dividing by the amount of datapoints will not cut it.

I hope it is clear what I'm trying to achieve here.
Thanks

*EDIT*

Let's say the data looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Value'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 
1, 0]
df['Timestamp'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=len(df), 
freq='15T')
df.plot(x='Timestamp', y='Value')
```

I can't split it on the zeros with partitioning, I cannot find anything online where a dataset is split everytime there is a zero.
Thanks.

Comment: What format is the dataset in? Why does partitioning everywhere the graph hits zero not successfully split the data into peaks? Sample data is easier to understand than a description.

Comment: It will be helpful if this is explained with some sample dataset. Otherwise it is hard to understand the transformation required.

Comment: @butterflyknife I will look into partitioning, did not know that was a thing. Will make a small sample dataset if that does not give me an answer. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something for you, but (a) it may have off-by-one errors, and (b) there needs to be some manual fudging at the first and last rows of the dataframe, if `Value` isn't zero for these rows. Disclaimers dispensed, here goes.

First, (1) put in columns indicating when a row is the beginning of a shift, and when it's at the end. At least for me, this involved some fumbling around with the parameters of the `shift()` calls. (2) Calculate the area under the graph for the 15-min time period represented by each row, using the trapezium rule. (3) Add a column to store ID's of each peak later. So far we have:

```
# (1)
df["start_peak"] = df["Value"].shift(-1).ne(0) & df["Value"].eq(0)
df["end_peak"] = (df["Value"].shift(-1).eq(0) & df["Value"].ne(0)).shift(1) 

# (2)
df["Area"] = 0.5 * 0.25 * (df["Value"] + df["Value"].shift(-1))

# (3)
df["peak_ID"] = pd.NaT # (3)
```

Now we need to loop through the rows of the dataframe and assign peak IDs to each row. The logic I chose was: (4) if it's the start of a peak, then the ID of the peak is the timestamp, (5) if it's not in a peak, then the ID is undefined (`pd.NaT`), and (6) otherwise the ID is the timestamp from the beginning of the peak. Note that there are a few ways to iterate down the rows of a dataframe (`iterrows, iteritems, itertuples`), but in general you should avoid it when you can. I don't think we can avoid it here.

```
previous_peak_id = pd.NaT
for (i, row) in df.iterrows():
    if row["start_peak"]:                         # (4)
        df.loc[i, "peak_id"] = row["Timestamp"]   # Just setting row["peak_id"] does not affect the main dataframe.
        previous_peak_id = row["Timestamp"]
    elif not(row["end_peak"]):                    # (6)
        df.loc[i, "peak_id"] = previous_peak_id
    else:
        pass                                      # (5) already assigned a pd.NaT
```

Finally, we group the rows of the dataframes into groups where the `peak_id` are the same, and sum the `Area` for each group. This adds up the trapezium slices for each `peak_id`, thus summing the area under each peak.

```
df.groupby(["peak_id"]).sum()["Area"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed does what I wanted it to do. Eventually I found another way to achieve my goal by means of a conditional loop keeping track of the amount of energy, giving me a little more insight. But I needed this solution to verify I was on the right track. Thanks so much!